# Чтение из папки raw

Tags: java, android, listview

У меня есть две `Activity`. В обеих есть `ListView`. Когда нажимаю на список первого `Activity`, то откроется первый файл из папки `raw`, но, когда нажимаю на список второго `Activity`, то откроется тот файл, который открылся при нажатии на список первого `Activity`. И так идёт дальше. Если сказать кратко, то при нажатии на каждый список обе `Activity` откроют одинаковые файлы. Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на список второго `Activity` открылся второй файл из папки `raw`, a не файл который открылся при нажатии на список первого `Activity`

Код `MainActivity`

```
private ListView lv1;

//Создаем массив разделов:
private String lv_arr[] = {

        "Список-1",//n0
        "Список-2",//n1
};


/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    // Получим идентификатор ListView
    lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    //устанавливаем массив в ListView
    lv1.setAdapter(
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lv_arr));
    lv1.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    //Обрабатываем щелчки на элементах ListView:
    lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
            //Позиция элемента, по которому щелкнули
            String itemname = new Integer(position).toString();

            Intent intent = new Intent();

            intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, ViewActivity.class);

            Bundle b = new Bundle();

            //defStrID содержит строку, которую отправим через itemname в другое Activity
            b.putString("defStrID", itemname);

            intent.putExtras(b);

            //запускаем Intent
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Код `ViewActivity`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //скрываем заголовок

    setContentView(R.layout.view);


    //скрываем строку состояния

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    String itemname = "n" + bundle.getString("defStrID"); //получаем строку и формируем имя ресурса

    Context context = getBaseContext(); //получаем контекст

    //читаем текстовый файл из ресурсов по имени
    String text = readRawTextFile(context, getResources().getIdentifier(itemname, "raw", "ru.akmaltilloev.frameeditguide"));

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    String summary = "<!Doctype html><html><head><meta charset=utf-8></head><body>" + text + "</body></html>";
    myWebView.loadData(summary, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "utf-8"); //загружаем текст в webview
}

public static String readRawTextFile(Context ctx, int resId) //читаем текст из raw
{
    InputStream inputStream = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(resId);

    InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
    BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);
    String line;
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        while ((line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
            text.append(line);
            text.append('\n');
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
    return text.toString();
}
```

Comment: Код покажите, чтобы было видно, что исправлять.

Comment: Добавил кода. В обе активити стоит этот код

Comment: Ваш заголовок не соответствует сути вопроса. У вас проблема не в самом чтении из папки, а в том что не знаете ЧТО читать из нее. Переформулируйте, пожалуйста.

Comment: А что писать в заголовке?

Comment: Во `ViewActivity` показывается одно и то же, при клике на любой элемент? Добавьте его код тоже.

Comment: По конкретнее `ListView` открывает файлы по порядке. Нажимаю на первый список открывается первый файл из папки `raw`. Нажимаю на второй список откроется второй файл из папки `raw`.

Comment: Добавил код из `MainActivity` и из `ViewActivity`

Comment: Может у вас содержимое файлов n0 и n1 одинаковое? По коду ошибок я не заметил.

Comment: Нет. В один из файлов много текста, а в другой пару слов написал.